# Add a floating action bar in Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

How to add a floating action bar in Appcelerator . I have designed the widget and would like to place it over a ScrollView . The widget should be always on the bottom right and should not move with the scroll view .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add it to the parent view/window of your `ScrollView`. E.g.

```
<Window>
  <ScrollView />
  <Widget />
</Window>
```

and it will be on top of your ScrollView and stay at the desired place (use tss to set right and bottom to a value)